# Bootstrap Carousel with instafeed.js (loop two images)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So I have the following JS:-

```
// InstaFeed

var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'ajith',
    clientId: '467ede5a6b9b48ae8e03f4e2582aeeb3',
    limit: 20,
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    resolution: "low_resolution",
    template: '<div class="item"><img src="{{image}}"/></div>',
    after: function () {
        $('#instafeed > div:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
    }
});
userFeed.run();
```

With the following HTML:-

```
<span id="insta-container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000000" data-ride="carousel">
        <div id="instafeed" class="carousel-inner"></div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Basically each item contains one image, I want to display two images per item. At the moment it is:-

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BBnf3UjHPyH/" target="_blank"><img class="img-insta" src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12716973_1720509661501439_1218058765_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE4MjA1MzU2ODI4NTA0Nzk0Mw%3D%3D.2" alt="Got my Magic Mouse 2 #apple"></a>
</div>
```

What I need is:-

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BBnf3UjHPyH/" target="_blank"><img class="img-insta" src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12716973_1720509661501439_1218058765_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE4MjA1MzU2ODI4NTA0Nzk0Mw%3D%3D.2" alt="Got my Magic Mouse 2 #apple"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BBnf3UjHPyH/" target="_blank"><img class="img-insta" src="//scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12716973_1720509661501439_1218058765_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE4MjA1MzU2ODI4NTA0Nzk0Mw%3D%3D.2" alt="Got my Magic Mouse 2 #apple"></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Maybe you should remove your Instafeed clientID ?

Comment: It's not my ID, it's one I found on codepen @ThinkTank